# Heat Equation IBVP on the Quarter plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have come across the following Heat equation IBVP but I am not quite sure how to solve it:

$$v_t = kv_{xx} \ \  \ \  \ \  ( 1 < x < \infty, \ \ 0 < t < \infty) ,$$
$$ v(x,0) = \delta (x - x_0) \ \  \ \  \ \  \mathrm{for} \ \ t = 0, \ \ x_0 > 1  $$
$$ v(1,t) = 0 \ \  \ \  \ \  \mathrm{for} \ \ x = 1 $$
$$ v(\infty,t) = 0 \ \  \ \  \ \  \mathrm{for} \ \ x = \infty. $$

Due to the Dirac delta initial condition, I was thinking some form of fourier like transformation is needed, but I am not sure given the boundary conditions if that will work.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the 1D heat kernel:
$$v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} e^{-x^2/(4 k t)}.$$
First, shift it so that the initial conditions line up:
$$v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} e^{-(x-x_0)^2/(4 k t)}.$$
This does not satisfy your Dirichlet boundary conditions; however you can fix it by applying the reflection principle:

$$v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} e^{-(x-x_0)^2/(4 k t)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} e^{-(x-[2-x_0])^2/(4 k t)}.$$

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for helping me with this. Can you please provide me a link to the reflection principle you are using. Sorry I am rather new to pdes and the only reflection principle I am aware of is the one associated with Brownian motion.

Comment: Check out section 5.3 of http://math.tut.fi/~piche/pde/notes05.pdf